# UseMnemonic is being affected by FlatStyle on a Button

Tags: c#, button

I'm trying to enable UseMnemonic on a button so that the amprasand (&) will show up for me.  The works fine unless I set the buttons flatStyle to System (all other flatstyles are fine).

Labels work fine with the same flatStyle, this seems to be specific to buttons.

Does any one know why this happens or a way behind it?

At the moment the only thing I can think of is ignore the UseMnemonic and add and extra & if one is found.

Also something else weird is that sometimes the & gets replaced with an underscore (_) but I can't yet reproduce this at will...

Far from the most effective code but something I through together to test this:

```
  public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.label1.Text = "hello & goodbye";
        this.button1.Text = "1&2";
        this.label3.Text = this.button1.UseMnemonic.ToString();
        this.label4.Text = this.button1.FlatStyle.ToString();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch (count)
        { 
            case 0:
            case 1:
                this.label1.UseMnemonic = this.button1.UseMnemonic = false;
                this.label1.FlatStyle = this.button1.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.System;
                count = 2;
                break;
            case 2:
                this.label1.UseMnemonic = this.button1.UseMnemonic = false;
                this.label1.FlatStyle = this.button1.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
                count = 3;
                break;
            case 3:
                this.label1.UseMnemonic = this.button1.UseMnemonic = false;
                this.label1.FlatStyle = this.button1.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Popup;
                count = 4;
                break;
            case 4:
                this.label1.UseMnemonic = this.button1.UseMnemonic = false;
                this.label1.FlatStyle = this.button1.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Standard;
                count = 5;
                break;
            case 5:
                this.label1.UseMnemonic = this.button1.UseMnemonic = true;
                this.label1.FlatStyle = this.button1.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.System;
                count = 6;
                break;
            case 6:
                this.label1.UseMnemonic = this.button1.UseMnemonic = true;
                this.label1.FlatStyle = this.button1.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
                count = 7;
                break;
            case 7:
                this.label1.UseMnemonic = this.button1.UseMnemonic = true;
                this.label1.FlatStyle = this.button1.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Popup;
                count = 8;
                break;
            case 8:
                this.label1.UseMnemonic = this.button1.UseMnemonic = true;
                this.label1.FlatStyle = this.button1.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Standard;
                count = 1;
                break;   
        }


        this.label3.Text = this.button1.UseMnemonic.ToString();
        this.label4.Text = this.button1.FlatStyle.ToString();
```

Comment: Maybe it works like menus? You need to press Alt to show the underlining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I follow.  But to get the ampersand to show up, you have to double it.  Fix:

```
        this.button1.Text = "1&&2";
```

Comment: I know you use the &&, however as the text for the buttons is being passed to me by another part of the code this would involve doing a string replace.  I'd prefer to use the IseMnemonic attribute whcih should cause the & to show up and it does in most cases, but if i set the flatstyle of the button to system it doesn't!

Comment: Erm, no, you cannot use IsMnemonic, it just tells you if there's a specific letter in the string that's prefixed with &.  I don't see the problem with using Replace(), you certainly should use that.  Yes, the FlatStyle is flaky but it isn't something you'd ever change but in the designer.

Comment: Not IsMnemonic, slight typo in the comment, UseMnemonic.  "UseMnemonic - If true, the first character preceded by an ampersand(&) will be used as the button's mnemonic key." from visual studio.  By setting this value to false the ampersand inthe text should just show up.

Comment: It will, when you press a key.  Not when drawing the text, sadly.  These kind of buglets are not uncommon in winforms although it probably was by design.